# AT command sent within the SMS text from python

Tags: python, at-command, pyserial

I need help with a piece of code I'm using to send weather forecast via SMS with a Huawei 3G dongle.

It worked, but here's what I receive :

```
AT+CMGF=1
AT+CMGS="+12345678"
It's partly cloudy and 20C now in Wahren.
```

Why I am receiving those `AT` strings?

```
import pywapi
import string
import serial


weather_com_result = pywapi.get_weather_from_weather_com('AGXX0006')
sms_text = "It's " + string.lower(weather_com_result['current_conditions']['text']) + " and " + weather_com_result['current_conditions']['temperature'] + "C now in Wahren.\n\n"

dongle = serial.Serial(port="COM6",baudrate=460800,timeout=0,rtscts=0,xonxoff=0)


def sendatcmd():
    number = "+12345678"
    dongle.write('AT+CMGF=1\r')
    dongle.write('AT+CMGS="' +number+'"\r')
    dongle.write(str(sms_text)+"\r")
    dongle.write(chr(26))
    dongle.close()
    print "sent"

sendatcmd()
```

Comment: how does Python get access to the processor like that (so that it can read/write AT commands). In Android, that access is provided by the Radio Interface Layer (RIL), and userland does *not* have access to it.

Comment: Since the OS sees the USB as a com port, and the python serial library is being used, I don't think the AT commands are being processed by the host processor at all, but rather just being forwarded to the serial/USB interface as data for interpretation only by the dongle, just like any other serial data would be.

Comment: Is the carriage return after the SMS text required? http://www.diafaan.com/sms-tutorials/gsm-modem-tutorial/at-cmgs-text-mode/ Indicates otherwise. It may be confusing the parser.

Comment: @StaceyAnne The text is not sent when i remove them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to first send an ATE0 command in order to turn echo off, otherwise each command will be echoed by the modem.

I used to program GSM modems, but don't have any hardware to test it now. Try inserting this before the first AT command:

```
dongle.write('ATE0\r')
```

Comment: Which message was empty?
PS: you should wait for the modem answers (OK or ERROR) and parse them, otherwise you have no guarantee that what you expect is happening

Comment: I put the line before the first AT command in the function as you told me and i got an empty SMS text.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what your goal is. In its default configuration, the modem will echo all the AT commands you write. With ATE0, it stops echoing the commands but they are processed nonetheless. The string is the SMS you want to send, if its works, the recipient of the SMS should receive it, but it doesn't need to be echoed by your modem for this.

Comment: Do you receive the SMS if you don't send ATE0 first? It shouldn't have any influence on the operation at all normally.